# Tinymce custom plugin assets not available for rails 3 app in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, tinymce, rubber

I have added a tinymce custom plugin in app/assets/tinymce/plugins/imagegallery/plugin.js and other related files in app/assets/tinymce/plugins/imagegallery/

It works fine in development on local machine. But, in production I get 404 NOT FOUND error.

```
http://<url>/assets/tinymce/plugins/imagegallery/plugin.js
```

I use rubber and deploy to Amazon EC2. Is there any rails asset configuration which I am missing? I am of the opinion that app/assets are already added in the asset pipeline. In application.js file, I have also tried adding "require tinymce". But, it did not help.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just try to run the application production environment in local machine. Just check is it working properly.

Comment: thanks sandip. I have tried running it and it does not work. I have overcomed the problem by adding as a plugin from a fork of imageupload plugin. See, https://github.com/svisamsetty/tinymce-rails-imageupload. In this, there are few line which was added in the rake task of the gem in lib/tasks to install tinymce assets. I am not sure how to do the same thing using asset pipeline. A more robust solution would be helpful for future purposes to others as well.